# Can I block an individual from a question

Tags: support

I asked a question today about patterns it was answered by several people, one of the answerering users has little understanding and has not read the question properly but has repeatedly made comments about OOP fundamentals in a tone suggesting superiority.

That's not that unusual and not something to report but it's a bit annoying and, now I added my own answer (because none of the answers had found what I was looking for) he has again taken to spamming me with comments (as well as downvoting the answer)

Does SO provide any way to block a user just from one question?

(To be clear I don't want to simply block myself from being able to see his activity like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5879/create-a-blacklist-to-keep-from-seeing-certain-users) suggests, I actually want him to not be able to continue to downvote opposing answers and post comments everyone else will see)

Answer (score 21):

No, you can't.

Comment: I thought that might be the case because I couldn't find something myself. Is there at least a way to block further comments? He added another in the time I was writing this. I don't really want to block anyone from answering but do I have to deal with the comments?

Comment: @NickCardoso again. No, you can't. If it's abusive, flag for moderator attention (although "I don't like what they're saying" or "they are wrong" is NOT abusive)

Comment: @NickCardoso There is no way for you to do so.  A moderator could lock the post, preventing all comments, votes, and edits to that post, although the fact that you don't like the comments someone is posting (so long as they're appropriate for the site, which these are) isn't grounds for locking a post.

Comment: @NickCardoso Just disengage and walk away.  Not everyone has to agree or get along.

Comment: They're not abusive but one could certainly argue they aren't *constructive*.

Comment: No I don't want it locked (I expect I will have to delete it once the meta effect kicks in anyway). @NathanOliver I wanted to ignore it but he adds other comments when I engage with anyone else

Comment: @NickCardoso And you just ignore him.  if you do not feed the fire it will burn out.

Comment: @NickCardoso - The only posts they commented on were yours and their own, and in both cases these comments were only in response to your own comments directed at them. Comments like "For the third time today you are wrong. I've tried to be polite but you insist on continued spam while you clearly don't know anywhere near enough to answer, but think you do." aren't particularly constructive, and just tend to fan the flames of an argument. If you stop commenting, I bet they will.

Comment: I had already stopped and when I answered  jaco0646 he commented more. Deleting responses but leaving his original (incorrect, contradictory) comment will mislead anyone else who does view that

Comment: @Nick pretty sure Brad can see deleted comments as well....

Comment: I assumed it was him who deleted it @Patrice - I mean any other visitors to the page, particularly anyone junior enough to be led by that comment

Comment: @NickCardoso Ignoring the merits of his comments and just throwing around personal insults is not the way to deal with that.  If you're actually concerned about that, and aren't willing to ignore the comment, then you need to engage in constructive dialog with the user, assume he's acting in good faith and has some basis for his statements, with the intent of both of you learning more about the topic at hand while discussing *the technical merits being raised* rather than attacking him as a person (whether he is right or wrong).  Just insulting has the opposite effect of what you're going for.

Comment: @Nick not my point. I meant that you seem to imply that that user spams you everywhere. When Brad said he didn't, you mention deleted comments, which makes it seem as if you say "he spams me everywhere but deletes his comments". My point is if Brad says he's only commenting on your post and his, he probably looks at the deleted comments as well, therefore it doesn't change anything. Yes that comment is misleading if wrong. If really wrong... then comment explaining why it is wrong. Don't attack the person, don't assume malice

Comment: Beyond the comment I quote above (which I deleted for obvious reasons) and the one responding to it, there was only a single other deleted comment stating "Override And Call Inherited Idiom, http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OverrideAndCallInheritedIdiom" that they left on their own answer below last comment listed. Again, it was only left in response to a question that was posed in a comment right before it. I don't really see any "spam" here.

Comment: I think that nick now wants to block @servy from this meta question!

Comment: @servy i haven't "thrown personal insults at him", I answered politely to his condescending comments on his non-answer and then I asked him to leave the question alone. He then commented again and when I responded to another user. I already stopped responding to his answer because he was not interested in answering my question about patterns, only implying I didn't understand my own code.

Comment: @NickCardoso "you clearly don't know anywhere near enough to answer, but think you do" that is what you consider not an insult? Politeness is just one facet of being nice.

Comment: @NickCardoso I read the comments.  Your comments needed to be *deleted by a mod* because they were inappropriate.  You were personally insulting his intelligence.  That you don't like his answer, or think his answer is wrong, doesn't make it not an answer.  It's perfectly fine for you to believe that an answer is wrong, but when you feel that way, if you do in fact decide to comment, you should be explaining why the content of the post is incorrect (or otherwise unhelpful) rather than attacking the intelligence of the author while ignoring the content of the post.  It makes *you* look wrong.

Comment: I consider that a fair comment. It's an observation given the condescension he exhibited in his answer despite not adding anything. He hadn't tried to answer, only to disparage my understanding of my own sample code. So why am I wrong to then reference his understanding?

Comment: @NickCardoso That you think personally insulting someone is "a fair comment" is precisely the problem here.  It's not.  Discuss the *content* of their post if you would like to; don't personally attack the author.  It actively hurts your position from the point of view of other readers when you engage in ad hominem attacks instead of discussing the merits of his argument, as well as being rude, unprofessional, and not at all acceptable behavior on this site.

Comment: Which was precisely the intent of his posts, which you consider acceptable

Comment: @NickCardoso His posts purely discuss the technical merits of the topic.  He in no way even *discussed* you as a person, let alone engaged in personal attacks the way you did.  He in fact did the *opposite*.  He responded to your personal attacks by *bringing the conversation back around to the technical merits of the post* while ignoring your rude and inappropriate behavior.  You personally may define "providing factual evidence that an argument someone made is wrong" to be a personal attack, but it is not.  Insulting a person's intelligence *is*  a personal attack.

Comment: Now you are exaggerating - attacks? What other attacks are you referencing and how exactly is the content of his post constructive or discussing technical merits? It tells me to use the very approach I used in my sample and rudely talks through it like I can't understand the fundementals

Comment: @NickCardoso Your inappropriate comments have been deleted, so I can't quote them.  That you feel the content was trivial for you doesn't make it unconstructive.  At best, it means that he didn't accurately understand your question.  That doesn't make his answer unconstructive or rude.  That you feel that the *technical merits* of his answer may not apply to your question doesn't mean his answer isn't sitting purely on technical merits, it just means they may be incorrect or not apply.  Posting an incorrect answer isn't offensive, insulting a person like you did *is*.

Comment: The single comment of mine that was deleted is on this thread.

Comment: What I wrote doesn't say anything more than you just did - he does not understand the question. Yet he (and you) think hostile explanation of my own sample as if I didn't understand is merited - but also adding multiple comments to my question, my answer and linking fundamentals in comments on his answer.

Comment: @NickCardoso I'm pretty sure that that's only half of the comment, from what I remember.

Comment: @NickCardoso First, I didn't say that he doesn't understand the question, I said that you think he doesn't understand the question.  That he made multiple comments on your question to discuss the question (specifically how it should be tagged) and on his answer (to specifically respond to your comments on it and to support his factual arguments) is *exactly the type of thing comments are there for*.  Linking to references to support his arguments, rather than insulting someone is exactly what we would expect people to be doing.

Comment: If you think that he is wrong *provide fact, evidence, and other argument to support that assertion*, don't just insult the person for making statement you feel is wrong.  Explaining why a given argument is wrong (or doesn't apply) is productive, it is when you are attacking the *author*, rather than *the content of the post* that it is problematic.  You didn't *explain why the contents of the post were wrong*, instead you insulted the author.  That's *radically different*.

Comment: It seems to me you've already formed your opinion before even considering what was written. Again I did cover this - "This doesn't answer the question or add anything the question doesn't already cover" - I phrased this as a question for him to expand, his response was again to ignore the question - about patterns and then continue to explain my own sample to me. I then gave him another chance to actually answer the question - again without any imaginary attack you referenced - and he did the same. 

Finally he posted a comment again condescendingly explaining strategy pattern.

Comment: You keep showing your bias in referring to his comments as factual mine are not - unlike other answers, his did not even address patterns until I posted my own answer. His last comment is even contradicting itself in stating that I'm wrong because the strategy pattern involves overriding methods to change behaviour - exactly what i am doing - and _tells_ me I don't need to change behaviour as if I'm unfamiliar with my own needs. How is it according to you, all of the above has technical merit and pointing out he lacks understanding of the question is a personal insult.

Comment: @NickCardoso Had you *just* said that in your comment, it wouldn't have been a personal attack.  (It's also wrong; you asked what term applied to a given example, he listed terms for what you did that weren't in the question, but that that sentence of your comment is wrong isn't why it's inappropriate.)  It's the fact that you then went on from there to insult his intelligence that makes it a personal attack; you should have instead explained why the answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That he responded to the comment of yours saying he didn't answer the question of what the terminology of your example is by *explicitly stating the terminology of your example* is providing exactly the information you specifically asked him for.  He didn't ignore it at all; he only ignored your personal attack.

Comment: @NickCardoso That last comment of your is proving my point.  You can think that his answer is *wrong*.  You can feel that his facts are *incorrect*.  That doesn't change the fact that he is *discussing the question that you're asking* while your comments *were not even discussing the question*.  You were insulting *him*, while he was *discussing the topic that your question was about*.  Whether he was factually correct or incorrect, that behavior is acceptable.  Attacking people *instead of discussing the topic* is *unacceptable* regardless of how factually correct either person is.

Comment: Again. There was no personal attack. That's your own assumption. He doesn't understand the question but keeps being condescending - it's not an attack to say that. My question is clear - "Whats the name of the pattern" and repeated in the body "My question is what is the name of this pattern". I never once asked for terminology for fundamental oop principles. You're happily ignoring the facts here to support the opinion you've already formed.

Comment: @NickCardoso Yes, there *is* a personal attack.  You're not discussing *the content* of the post, you're insulting the author of the post as a person.  That's a personal attack.  I'm not ignoring the facts, I've stated like a dozen times now that *I'm not taking a position either way* on their accuracy.  I've stated that the answer is addressing the content of the question, regardless of its accuracy.  If you think he hasn't accurately described those patterns then *explain why you feel those don't adequately describe them*, don't insult his intelligence for providing them.

Comment: You are taking a position. You're taking the position that it's fine for someone to be repeatedly condescending to the point of implying another author doesn't grasp even fundamentals about the subject but that it's not fine to then point out that that user doesn't actually know about the subject (which is in reference to the content they've posted). Where is the invisible line? Because that's exactly the same thing: both are saying the other doesn't know about said subject

Comment: @NickCardoso No, I didn't take that position.  I've stated my position as being that it's appropriate to discuss the technical merits of a post, even if you disagree with someone over some of those arguments, and that it's not okay to attack the author while ignoring the actual arguments that he's making.  That's the line.  Talk about the content of the question, not the person writing that content.  It's *super* straightforward.  If the answer is explaining concepts that you understand and fails to provide the answer you're looking for then *say that* rather than insulting the author.

Comment: As I've said - I didn't attack him personally and I can't read it that way, like you've chosen to. I didn't call him stupid or comment on his English or appearance or anything else personal. 

His condescending comments were aimed at my understanding and my comment the same, _obviously_ in relation to the content he is posting, there is nothing else for it to be related to because I have no prior history with him. 

The invisible line lies where you decide one is a personal matter and the other is 'discussing technical merits' (which it does not).

Comment: @NickCardoso You attacked him as a person, not the content that he posted.  That's a personal attack.  You specifically insulted his intelligence; in effect you *did* call him stupid (or at least the functional equivalent).  That you attacked his intelligence instead of his appearance doesn't make it any less of a personal attack.  The aspects of his person that you attacked isn't important, what's important is that you attacked *him* and not *the content of the answer, devoid of the context of the author*.